# Polychromatic number of plane

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

Let $\chi$ be the least size of a partition of plane into pieces each of which omits unit distance. Let $\chi_p$ be the least size of a partition of plane into pieces each of which omits some distance. So $\chi_p \leq \chi$. It is known that $4 \leq \chi_p \leq 6$ - See Theorem 4.2 and Problem 6.1 in A. Soifer, The mathematical coloring book. The proof of $\chi_p \geq 4$ given in Soifer's book (due to Alexei Merkov) makes a clever use of translations of Mosers spindle which was the finite configuration used earlier for a proof of $\chi \geq 4$. In view of the recent discovery of finite unit distance planar graphs witnessing $\chi \geq 5$, I have been wondering if someone has tried to use them to improve the lower bound for $\chi_p$ as well. So the question is:
Is $\chi_p \geq 5$?

Comment: Soifer's story how a mixup in translation between решение (solution) and разрешение (permission) prevented due credit for the Russian mathematician who proved $\chi_p\leq 6$ is a [good read](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-0-387-74642-5_6)